# Use Array as Indexing Mask for Multidimensional Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following arrays:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 2, 3))
```

and

```
b = np.zeros((2, 2))
```

Now I want to use b to access a, s.t. at each for index i,j we take the z-th element of a, if b[i, j] = z.
Meaning for the above example the answer should be [[0, 3], [6, 9]].
I feel this is very related to np.choose, but yet somehow cannot quite manage it.
Can you help me?

Comment: yes thank you. could you just add a few more details on your solution? e.g. why do i need [:, None] for the first indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches could be suggested.

With `explicit` range arrays for [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
m,n = b.shape
out = a[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n),b.astype(int)]
```

With [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) -

```
np.take_along_axis(a,b.astype(int)[...,None],axis=2)[...,0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])

In [45]: b
Out[45]: 
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])

In [46]: m,n = b.shape

In [47]: a[np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n),b.astype(int)]
Out[47]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [6, 9]])

In [48]: np.take_along_axis(a,b.astype(int)[...,None],axis=2)[...,0]
Out[48]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [6, 9]])
```